# Most useful automated tasks?

Tags: automation, scheduled-tasks

I've just read the [Most useful AutoHotKey scripts](https://superuser.com/questions/7271/most-useful-autohotkey-scripts) question and that got me thinking about automation and repetitive tasks.

Which automated task, once you got it in place and functioning, really made a difference in how you go about your day?

Answer (score 1):

- [Speeding up podcasts in iTunes](https://superuser.com/questions/81045/podcast-playback-faster-than-1x-speed-on-ipod/92846#92846)
- Setting up robocopy on all my machines to move all downloaded items to my home server when it's available.
- Set up robocopy to keep SysInternals up to date locally (On my Win7 machine: `robocopy /E /DCOPY:T /MT:2 \\live.sysinternals.com\tools C:\Path\To\SysinternalsSuite /XF Thumbs.db`)

Comment: I just found the iTunes speed x2 button (accidentally :) on my iPod last week!

Answer (score 1):

Backing up my VM's to a USB external drive in the middle of the night; once a month or so, I just plug it into another PC, fire the VM's up and verify I could work if the main host was dead.

Answer (score 1):

Website macros! I work with many websites (Email, salesfore, SAP web client, intranet, blogs, Stackoverflow etc) each day and automated *all* routine logins and navigation with [iMacros](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/) (free Firefox addon).